# How to reset ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular

## State

I have a main component `MainComponent` which holds a form.
I have a second component `MetricComponent` which implements `ControlValueAccessor` and is used with `formControlName` in the `MainComponent` html.

The `MainComponent` form is created with the following method :

```
initForm(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [{ value: 'id', disabled: true }],
      metric: [this.metric]
    });
```

## Problem

When I disable the form in the `MainComponent` with `this.form.disable()` everything is disabled and `setDisabledState()` is called in the `MetricComponent`

But then I decided to recreate the form by call the `initForm()` method. When I do this, the `setDisabledState()` is not called and I have an enabled `MainComponent.form` with a disabled `MetricComponent`.

How am I supposed to reset the `MetricComponent` state once the form has changed ?

Answer (score 1):

I was using angular 14, it seems to be resolved in angular 16.